# Google Meet: Allow microphone but not camera?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to enable Google Chrome/Meet to use a microphone but not a camera?  I'm not a Chrome user, but have to use it for some online training where I need to hear/speak but not use the camera

Comment: Questions about Google platforms are off-topic unless you are asking about the use of your computer hardware. In that case, there is no way for us to know how to help you when we know nothing about your computer/webcam. Please use the [edit] feature to add details. If you are not worried about high-tech solution, see my answer below.

Comment: If the permissions to use a Microphone and Camera are the same permission, then both have to be granted, it sounds like that is indeed the case if there isn't an option to only one or the other.

Comment: @CharlieRB This site isn't restricted to questions about computer hardware.  "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

    computer hardware,
    computer software, or
    personal and home computer networking"

Comment: I know that. If you look a little closer, you will see where online applications, like Google (Drive, Sheets, YouTube, etc), are off topic. I am not familiar with Meet, so I did not down vote or vote to close. It appears Meet may be software that resides on the computer, therefore making it on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get yourself a roll of electircal tape.

[image]

Cut a small piece and put it over your camera.

Comment: Actually, I already did that.  But it seems to me that it should be possible to do it via Meet settings.

Comment: Some kind of painters tape would be better. Good electrical tape is not incredibly easy to remove cleanly. Or just a thick piece of paper folded over. Or you can get purpose built after market webcam privacy shields online.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic solution that will apply to even non Google apps:

Remove all mic/camera permission in Chrome for that site, then do a call that requires only microphone and grant that access alone. After that make a video call and when it asks for video permission, deny that.

If you did a video call initially, it grouped microphone and camera in a single permission item... which you can't break apart later.

However, that seems to have stopped working well this morning for me as Google Meet now continually harasses you to allow camera as well.

Comment: But the suggestion about the tape is still my preferred solution! There are some nice magnetic sliding covers that work well for laptops and phones that you can stick on as well...

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the meet website and click the lock in the search box the permissions should come up and just block the camera

Answer (score 0):

These procedures are for the chrome browser but I guess there have to be similar methods for other browsers.

1. go to google meet and create a new meeting.
2. on top bar accept the access of camera and microphone.
3. Go to the chrome setting and then `privacy and security` tab.
4. click on the `camera` option and delete `google meet` access to your camera.

This leads to just microphone access.